# How to write to a file in a globally-installed Node module?

Tags: node.js, permissions, npm

### Context

I am developing a [Node module](https://github.com/MattiSG/Watai) to be installed as a CLI executable. Hence, I am packaging it for usage with NPM, and [advising](http://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#preferGlobal) to install it [globally](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/).

### Problem

However, as a CLI program, I'd like to write to a log file. This works fine on a local install, but of course less fine in a global install: the program is placed in `/usr/local/lib/…` by NPM, which has to be run as `sudo` to write there.

Then, when a user then tries to run the tool, it fails due to `EACCES`: the log folder and files can not be created.

### Steps taken

I successfully used a [`postinstall` script](http://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html) to create the logging destinations while still su (`mkdir log && touch log/execution.log`), but those files are then owned by `nobody`, and may not be opened by the tool. The problem shifts a bit, but ends up being quite the same.

### Question

**Is there a way to give an NPM module the right to write in its own directory?**

#### More specific questions

What would you advise in my case? I have thought of the following solutions:

1. Write the log file in the execution CWD. This is ugly, and not so safe since the CWD could be not writable too.
2. Write the log file to a preset writable log file, such as `~/.mytool/log`, but I don’t like at all spreading files all over the user’s machine.
3. Ask the user for a log file destination. Extremely annoying.
4. `chmod 666` the global log file. Less ugly but insecure.

Is there any common practice to handle such an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to give write permissions in its own directory to a globally-installed Node module.

Indeed, to allow for global install, i.e. to be able to write in `/usr/local/lib`, NPM has to be run as root through `sudo`. However, when doing so, NPM will [downgrade its user to `nobody`](https://github.com/isaacs/npm#permissions-when-using-npm-to-install-other-stuff):

> As of version 0.3, it is recommended to run npm as root. This allows npm to change the user identifier to the `nobody` user prior to running any package build or test commands.

All [package scripts](http://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html) are run as `nobody`, and therefore cannot override this setting.

It is a safety feature that also prevents any unauthorized post-install modifications to an installed module, making installed modules trustable.

---

You should probably try to find a default place for your log that makes sense in your business logic. Defining a user-overridable (through a CLI switch) global writable log such as `~/.yourTool/log` would be nice, but Node does not expand `~`, so finding a cross-platform global logging destination seems a bit difficult.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: @Roecrew What? That NPM stil downgrades? Yes: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3849. That Node does not expand `~`? Yes: just type `node -e 'console.log(require("path").resolve("~"))'` at a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like that:

- Log in CWD as default
- Log path can be given as argument (like `go -l /path/to/log`)
- Error if log file not writable